USB 3.0 Ports Not Receiving Any Power After Replacing Motherboard
Product: HP Z820 Base Model Workstation Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 (64-Bit)
Motherboard HP Workstation Z820 V2 Dual CPU LGA2011 DDR3 Motherboard. USB Controller not noted other than that on the motherboard.
All USB 3.0 ports are not working both rear and front since replacing my motherboard. I doubt it is hardware related because it is affecting all USB 3.0 ports only. I have tried reinstalling the chipset drivers from the HP website, disabling from the Device Manager and restarting, and resetting BIOS to factory defaults. None of these worked even after restarting.
I have made sure that the USB drive I am testing with is working on other Windows 10 machines with USB 3.0 ports. The USB drive is getting no power, no lights on it turn on, unlike when I use it with other machines.
How do I get my USB 3.0 ports to work?

Can you please add the model and type of your USB-3.0-Controller with an edit to the question.

Have you tried any other USB devices ? Preferrably self powered ones or something simple like a USB stick ?

Yes, I am using a USB stick. It works fine on USB 3.0 on other machines and on USB 2.0 on this machine. Just not USB 3.0 on this machine.
